# X509Certificate encryption/decryption

Tags: xml, encryption-asymmetric

I'm just starting to learn XML security. We have VS-2005 & ASP.Net 2.0. I want to send XML to a outside URL and it needs to be encrypted. I'm doing exactly what the MSDN articles [ms229744](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx) & [ms229943](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229943.aspx) are doing, but when doing the DecryptDocument() method, I keep getting the "Unable to retrieve the decryption key." I'm using our SSL web certificate, and I currently use X509Certificate to digitally sign the XML and it works fine.

I also asked somebody else to try this from a different shop and they are getting the same error. Is there a documented problem with the X509 decryption methods? In test code below, I'm posting the XML to another web page that is attempting to decrypt the XML. What I don't understand is how the DecryptDocument() method can work if it doesn't even check to see if the Public key is embedded. Is this the problem? If so, how do I check to make sure it is embedded in the XML? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
Private Function EncryptXml(ByVal xmlDoc As XmlDocument, ByVal Cert As X509Certificates.X509Certificate2) As XmlDocument

   Dim dataNodes As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("Agency")
   If dataNodes.Count <> 1 Then
       Return Nothing 
   End If  
   Dim elementToEncrypt As XmlElement = CType(xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Agency")(0), XmlElement)
   Dim eXml As New EncryptedXml()
   Dim Key As RSACryptoServiceProvider = CType(Cert.PrivateKey, RSACryptoServiceProvider)
   Dim edElement As EncryptedData = eXml.Encrypt(elementToEncrypt, Cert)
   EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, False)
   Return xmlDoc 
End Function



Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load 
If Not IsPostBack Then
   If Request.Form("hdnSignedXML") IsNot Nothing Then
   Dim strXML As String = Request.Form("hdnSignedXML")
   Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument
   xmlDoc.LoadXml(strXML)
   xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = True
   Response.ContentType = "text/plain"
   Response.Write(strXML)

   Dim exml As New Xml.EncryptedXml(xmlDoc)
   exml.DecryptDocument()
   xmlDoc.Save("C:/inetpub/TestExampleDecrypted.xml")


   Response.End()

End If

End Sub
```

jP

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, your web process can't access the private key.  I ran into the same thing once, and posted an answer in this item:

[Set read permission for certificate from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255747/set-read-permission-for-certificate-from-command-line/7264187#7264187)

In case you still have issues, for our encryption routines, we referenced http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163454.aspx